# Universal Windows 10 image

Tags: backup, disk-image, windows-backup, acronis-trueimage

how to create universal windows image with necessary programs and drivers?

Comment: "so it will be suit to all kind model of PC" - If you create a generic image, you'll still need to go back in at the end and update all the device drivers, and if you make the image with for instance an AMD CPU on an MSI motherboard with certain interfaces, i wouldn't use the same image on an Inter CPU on a Gigabyte motherboard with different interface options; you're just asking for trouble.

Comment: You probably won't be able to use Acronis for this. You might be able to use the Windows deployment tools/unattended Installation mechanisms to slipstream some/all of the additional stuff you'd want to include but essentially you would be running the regular Windows installation. As such you would be able to avoid problems @spikey_richie mentioned (to some extend, depending on what you do).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Acronis backup is not the right tool for creating or deploying Windows images.

You might use the official
[Windows 10 deployment tools](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/deployment/windows-deployment-scenarios-and-tools),
although the subject might be more technical than you would like.

There are some tools that can help in this task of creating a
bootable install media from your current installation:

- [NTLite](https://www.ntlite.com/) (free for personal purposes - probably the best-known)
- [Acronis Snap Deploy 5](https://www.acronis.com/en-us/business/enterprise-solutions/image-deployment/)
  ($9.99)
- [SmartDeploy](https://www.smartdeploy.com/) (trialware with registration, $23)